# Swift <<, ><, <=< and >=<

Tags: swift3

The following functions are defined in the Swift modules.  What are they used for?

```
public func <<T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func ><T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func <=<T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func >=<T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool
```

Comment: Operator overloading.

Comment: overloading which operator - and what does it do?

Comment: Looks like the ending `<` is just the beginning of `<T where T.RawValue : Comparable>`. Once you cut it out, they are just the usual comparison operators `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: The basic comparison operators (it's not << it's just <)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're definitely familiar with these operators. They're `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=`. It helps if they're written like this:

```
public func < <T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func > <T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func <= <T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool

public func >= <T where T.RawValue : Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool
```